# AJAX and PHP login failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

The result of the output is false alert, why is the alert always false? Whereas email and password are in accordance with in database.

PHP:

```
<?php 
    include 'db.php';

    $email  = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query); 

    if($row>0)
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
     else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
?>
```

AJAX:

```
    function ceklogin(){
        var email    = document.getElementById('mail').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'tes2.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {email: email, password: password},
                success: function(html) 
                {
                    alert(html);
                }
            });
    }

<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="mail" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" required>
    <button type="submit" class="w3ls-cart" onclick="ceklogin()">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try running the PHP file alone and check if it is working fine? Hope the SQL query you have written here is fine...

Comment: Is the password stored in plain text? Just wondering ^^

Comment: Set your data post with `'  '`, like, `data: {'email': email, 'password': password},`.

Comment: Check database FIle And Run php page separately

Comment: use json instead

Comment: try manually running the query with your pass email and password

Comment: @void yeah i check and running php file alone is working fine and that result 'true'.

Comment: @Virb does not working :(

Comment: @TarangP i check and is working fine ..

Comment: @Beginner manually running and the result true.. what wrong with my ajax ?

Comment: @illogic try console.log() your email and password variable to check if they are getting the value fine.

Comment: Have you included `jquery` library file?  Which is required to make `ajax` call.

Comment: check your network if your parameter are really pass by your ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your button type to `type='button'`

```
<button type="button" class="w3ls-cart" onclick="ceklogin()">Sign In</button>
```

Also please do not store passwords in plain-text. You'll be putting your users at risk of security hacks. use `password_hash()` to hash the password and `password_verify()` to verify that the entered password via `$_POST` is the same as the hashed one.

In your php script, turn on error reporting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); #place this at the top of the script
```

Also as @xander mentioned, add the following to turn on error reporting for `mysqli`

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
```

Comment: I would also turn on MySQLi error reporting or php might not show invalid SQL queries. I use this `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);` for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_num_rows()` function returns the number of rows in a result set. And when you use COUNT() or MAX(), there would always be one row giving/showing you the result set.

Instead of this, you should do `COUNT(*)` and check if that count is greater than 0.

Comment: So, what's the difference here? If there are no rows at all, it will return 0 rows. And hence `mysqli_num_rows($query)` will also return 0.

Answer (score 0):

First Check the data are flowing to your php page or not.

```js
function ceklogin(){
        var email    = document.getElementById('mail').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'tes2.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {'email': email, 'password': password},
                success: function(html) 
                {
                    alert(html);
                }
            });
    }
```

And in PHP page Check the POST data by

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: maybe add some explanations?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine. Try clearing your browsers cache and change your ajax script to;

```
function ceklogin(){
    var email    = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'tes2.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'email': email, 'password': password},
            **cache: false,**
            success: function(html) 
            {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
}
```